# How to Use Nginx Gzip, Cache, and SSL at the same time?

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm currently using Nginx with NodeJs and i'm trying to edit my nginx.conf file to allow caching.

With my current setup below I have SSL and GZIP working, but how can I add caching?
I get an error 404.
My files have the following structure: /root/Poplive/Dec5/public

In public I have a file (main-built.js) and the folders (/javascripts|/css), these are the files and folders im trying to cache.

What I tried....

1) I put the directive below inside location / {} in my nginx.conf below

```
location ~* /.*\.(/javascripts|main-built.js)$ {
expires 24h;
}
```

Result, no caching but GZIP works

Nginx.conf below

```
events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {

    upstream myapp {
        server 127.0.0.1:3100;
    }

#Add Gzip
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout   2;
    tcp_nodelay        on;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server {
        root /Poplive/Dec5/public;

        ssl_certificate /root/Poplive/Dec5/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /root/Poplive/Dec5/server.key;

        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
  if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
  }
        server_name poplive.co;





           location / {

 location ~* /.*\.(/javascripts|main-built.js)$ {
    expires 24h;
    }

proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-PROTO https;
            proxy_pass http://myapp/;

     }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is incorrect. I don't know what you want exactly, but I can still confirm it's incorrect.

```
location ~* /.*\.(/javascripts|main-built.js)$ {
```

Here's what wrong with that.

- If you want `/` character, you should escape it by using `\`. so it looks like `\/`
- When you wrote `\.(MoreRulesHere)`, that meant you want files like `.main-built.js`. But you aren't going to name your files like that, are you?
- By putting `$` at the end, you stated that `/javascripts` should be the ending. That is, it's a request of a folder.

I believe you meant to write (assuming since I can't exactly tell your intent).

```
location ~* \/(javascripts\/.*|main-built.js)$ {
```

That is everything in `javascripts` folder and a file called `main-built.js`. Because there is no `^` character at the beginning, it does not state that it needs to begin with above. So, it will match things like `/something/else/here/javascripts/foo` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to cache the main-built.js and javascripts folder files. First loading them as Gzip while caching them. The problem is i'm not exactly sure where to put location regex.